# Immutable type wrapper

Tags: java, immutability

I'm confused about Type wrappers being immutable when executing following code

```
static void inc(Integer nr)
{
    System.out.printf("1. inc() \t %d \n", nr);
    nr++;
    System.out.printf("2. inc() \t %d \n", nr);
} // inc()

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer nr1 = 10;
    System.out.printf("a. main() \t %d \n", nr1);
    inc(nr1);
    System.out.printf("b. main() \t %d \n", nr1);
} // main()
```

Executing it creates following output

```
  a. main()     10 
  1. inc()      10 
  2. inc()      11 
  b. main()     10
```

If a type wrapper is immutable, why then is the value increased between line "1. inc" and "2. inc"
and does line "b. main" print the same value as "1. main"?

thank you

Chris

Comment: What do you think `++` does and why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have no idea why you think that this question is a duplicate of the one you marked. The OP wants to know how the value of an immutable object changed because of a post-increment!!!!!!

Comment: @ChetanKinger Don't look at the question, look at the answers. They explain every part of OP's confusion.

Comment: This is a duplicate down to the method name.

Answer (score 2):

> If a type wrapper is immutable, why then is the value increased between line "1. inc" and "2. inc"

Because you're not actually mutating the existing `Integer` object - you're creating a new one (well, effectively - actually it'll use common cached objects, but the point is that the value of `nr` will refer to a different object after `nr++`). Think of this:

```
nr++;
```

As instead:

```
int tmp = nr.intValue();
tmp++;
nr = Integer.valueOf(tmp);
```

So the fact that you see the text representation of `nr` changing doesn't mean that the object it refers to has mutated - in this case, the cause is that `nr` itself has taken on a new value, referring to a different object.

You can see that with more diagnostics, too:

```
static void inc(Integer nr)
{
    Integer original = nr;
    System.out.printf("1. inc() \t %d \n", nr);
    nr++;
    System.out.printf("2. inc() \t %d \n", nr);
    // This will print 10
    System.out.printf("Original: %d\n", original);
}
```

> and does line "b. main" print the same value as "1. main"?

The reference is passed by value, just as it always is. That means `inc(nr1)` doesn't modify `nr1` at all - it refers to the same object it did before. As I said above, `inc` *also* doesn't modify the object (because the wrapper types are immutable). Therefore after the call, `nr1` refers to the same object wrapping the same value (10).

Comment: The OP also wants to know why the value of an immutable object changes when post-incremented.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: It doesn't. That's the point. I've explained both parts that the OP has asked about, as far as I can see...

Comment: @ChetanKinger as the answer says, it doesn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet My bad. The answer is implied.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: I think it's pretty explicit, actually. I've expanded it more. Of course, you can write your own answer if you think mine isn't clear enough.

Comment: I think, the part with the `tmp` variable is rather confusing. It’s better to emphasize that `nr++;` is just a short-hand for `nr = nr + 1;` here, which is just a short-hand for `nr = Integer.valueOf(nr.intValue() + 1);`; there is no temporary variable involved…

Comment: @Holger: I disagree - I think it's clearer to show one simple expression per line. Given that the intermediate expression effective *is* a temporary variable, I think it's entirely reasonable to break it down all the way.

Comment: Intermediate expressions *are not* temporary variables. That’s the point. Otherwise, by writing `tmp++;`, which is again a short-hand for `tmp = tmp + 1;` you would create another temporary variable.

Comment: @Holger: I view them as *effectively* equivalent to temporary variables. I personally view three statements each of which does one thing as simpler than one statement which does three things. But as I said to Chetan - if you think you have a clearer way of explaining it, add your own answer. I'm not going to change *my* answer to an explanation which *I* feel is less clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet I chose to ignore your first comment which said *Of course, you can write your own answer if you think mine isn't clear enough* because I assumed you might have overlooked the fact that the question is closed. Your second comment *if you think you have a clearer way of explaining it, add your own answer. I'm not going to change my answer to an explanation which I feel is less clear* is a bit out of line because none is asking you to change your answer but simply letting you know that it's confusing to others.

Comment: @Chetan: I had indeed overlooked that it is closed. But I still personally feel this is the clearest I can express it, and that the suggested changes would make the answer worse - therefore I will not be applying them.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your discussion with Holger is on a different aspect of your answer than the one you are having with me so let's not mix them. The question is a two part question. 1. Why does the value of an immutable object get incremented? 2. Why does the value of an immutable object remain the same when passed to a method? Your answer before your edit did not explain part 1 i.e, why does the value of the immutable object `nr` get incremented inside the `inc` method so that the second `print` statement in `inc` printed `11`. Part 1 may have been implied by Part 2 but in the most indirect way.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: Again, we'll have to agree to disagree. I think revision 1 already answered part 1, although it's clearer now. Anyway, I don't think this conversation is adding any value at this point...

Comment: @ChetanKinger You (or the OP if you're asking on behalf of them) will need to differentiate between object, reference, and variable.